# amazon ec2 does not seem to accept udp data

Tags: amazon-ec2, udp

Am using ffmpeg to receive data on udp protocol on Amazon ec2 e.g.

```
#> ffmpeg -i udp://0.0.0.0:2013 -f flv http://0.0.0.0:8090/live.ffm
```

but there does not seem to be any packets received. for test purposes, am trying to send data from local pc via ffmpeg as follows:

```
$> ffmpeg -i vdo.flv -f flv udp://<ec2-ip>:2013
```

netstat -lu also

The security group being used has all udp ports open.

however for the sake of testing the validity of ffmpeg command , also wrote in on local pc and it seems to receive without issue:

e.g:

Sender:

```
$> ffmpeg -i vdo.flv -f flv udp://localhost:2013
```

Receiver:

```
    $> ffmpeg -i udp://localhost:2013 -f flv udp.flv
```

**UPDATE**

tcpdump shows that data is coming to the EC2 instance but ffmpeg still doesnt seem to be getting that data

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the udp, did you ensure port 8090 tcp outgoing is available for your app?  I have not run into any major issues with udp in ec2, snmp for example has worked well.